# Service Error: Spreadsheet (line 16, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

The problem I have is that it worked perfectly a copyAndDelete function, but after I add new Projects it send me "Error service: Spreadsheets (line 16, file "Code")".

I try to delete the other projects but the problem continue. I made a new spreadsheet copying the script codes, and is the same.

The function is:

```
function copyAndDelete () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Registro!C2:C2");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reporte");
  // Determinar la ubicación de la primera fila vacía.
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();

  var lcol = 1; //# Columna izquierda que se está evaluando
  var tcol = 2; //# Columna donde estampamos la hora fecha actual.
  //
    var scol = destRange.getColumn(); 
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= tcol)
    {
      destSheet.getRange(destRange.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());  //Dispara el registro en la columna donde va el resultado
    }
  }
```

And the line it remarks is:

```
destSheet.getRange(destRange.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());  //Dispara el registro en la columna donde va el resultado
```

Please help me. I even try a suggestion of adding and delete las rows of the sheet and doesn`t works

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetApp buffers all non conflicting edits together. If you add SpreadsheetApp.flush() after each step you will see the problem is actually on copyTo(). You cannot copy to a range that doesn't exist. Some methods expand the sheet, but copyTo is not one of them.